# Change Button Image on Button click

Tags: android, xml

Selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_call_active_big" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <!-- pressed -->

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_call_normal_big"/>

</selector>
```

And on button background

```
 <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPhone"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_call_normal_big" />
```

Please advice on above . where i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the selector in place of the png file. Change

```
android:src="@drawable/btn_call_normal_big"
```

with

```
android:src="@drawable/nome_of_selector"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean isPressed=false
button.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);

    OnClickListener buttonListener= new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(isPressed){
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon1);
        }else{
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon2);
        }
        isPressed=!isPressed;
   }
};
```

Hope it will help you.

Also check below link

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/

this also might help you

Answer (score 0):

Remove src attribute and change the background attribute value to your selector file name.

```
  <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnPhone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/Selector"
         />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPhone"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/selector" />
```